# I've Heard Global Variables Are Bad, What Alternative Solution Should I Use?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've read all over the place that [global variables are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and alternatives should be used. In Javascript specifically, what solution should I choose.

I'm thinking of a function, that when fed two arguments (`function globalVariables(Variable,Value)`) looks if Variable exists in a local array and if it does set it's value to `Value`, else, `Variable` and `Value` are appended. If the function is called without arguments (`function globalVariables()`) it returns the array. Perhaps if the function is fired with just one argument (`function globalVariables(Variable)`) it returns the value of `Variable` in the array.

What do you think? I'd like to hear your alternative solutions and arguments for using global variables.

## How you would use `globalVariables();`

```
function append(){
    globalVariables("variable1","value1"); //globalVariables() would append variable1 to it's local array.
};

function retrieve(){
    var localVariable1 = globalVariables("variable1"); //globalVariables() would return "value1".
};

function retrieveAll(){
    var localVariable1 = globalVariables(); //globalVariables() would return the globalVariable()'s entire, local [persistently stored between calls] array.
};

function set(){
    globalVariables("variable1","value2"); //globalVariables() would set variable1 to "value2".
};
```

**Is this a [Singleton Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonPattern) BTW?**

In this specific scenario a function may set a variable at one point in time, and much later another function, maybe when a user submits a form, will need to get that variable. Therefore the first function couldn't pass the variable as an argument to the later function as it would never be called from the first.

Thank you, I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The primary reason why global variables are discouraged in javascript is because, in javascript all code share a single global namespace, also javascript has implied global variables ie. variables which are not explicitly declared in local scope are automatically added to global namespace. Relying too much on global variables can result in collisions between various scripts on the same page (read [Douglas Crockford's articles](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/)).

One way to reduce global variables is to use the [YUI module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). The basic idea is to wrap all your code in a function that returns an object which contains functions that needs to be accessed outside your module and assign the return value to a single global variable.

```
var FOO = (function() {
    var my_var = 10; //shared variable available only inside your module

    function bar() { // this function not available outside your module
        alert(my_var); // this function can access my_var
    }

    return {
        a_func: function() {
            alert(my_var); // this function can access my_var
        },
        b_func: function() {
            alert(my_var); // this function can also access my_var
        }
    };

})();
```

now to use functions in your module elsewhere, use `FOO.a_func()`. This way to resolve global namespace conflicts you only need to change the name of `FOO`.

Comment: crockford's article describing z33m's solution http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/

Answer (score 45):

Semantics my boy. Semantics.

Start with one global: myApp = {};
Everything should be in that. The only exception would be your AJAX library (there are some extreme exceptions like working with JSONP callbacks).

There should be very few properties in myApp. You'll want to hold your application properties in containers such as config or settings.

```
myApp = {
    config:{
        prop:1
    },
    settings:{
        prop:2
    },
    widgets:{
        List: function(props){},
        Item: function(props){}
    }
}
```

Then you may have more properties in lower modules, components, singletons and Class constructors (widgets).

This setup gives you the added benefit of being able to access any property from any other location since you can get it with the myApp global. However, you should use "this" whenever possible because the lookup is faster. And just set the property directly, don't bother with the pseudo getter/setter stuff. If you really need a getter/setter, code it for that specific use.

The reason your example doesn't work is it's too generic and you seem to be looking for an excuse to work in the global space.

And don't get clever with private variables. They're bad too:
http://clubajax.org/javascript-private-variables-are-evil/

Answer (score 10):

Global state causes problems in several areas.  One is code reuse.   When you access some global state that means the component must be aware of it's environment(something outside of itself).  You should avoid this as much as possible, because it makes the component unpredictable.

Say I have an object that accesses your globalVariables function and I want to use it in another page.  How do I know to define the globalVariables object or even how to define it?  However if you can pass the information into a constructor or as an argument to a function then I can easily determine what is required by the object.

Also when you access or modify the global scope then you risk affecting other objects.  This is why libraries like jquery use only a single name on the global scope(the least possible).  It lessens the possibility of conflict with other libraries.   In other words the global scope is out of your control, so it is dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

Using global variables is usually a bad practice, regardless of the language. They can especially be awkward when using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which I highly recommend).

Consider this piece of code I found:

```
if (typeof session != 'undefined' && !data.cart.request_status)
  data.input_definitions.passengers =
    inflate_passenger(session, data.input_definitions.passengers);
```

I had to ask around, where did the variable `session` come from? It did not appear in any code search. Eventually I discovered it was declared in another package from the company.

Code is like a joke: if you need to explain it, it's probably not that good.

**Workaround using ES6:**

If at Node, use `import` or `require` to bring the desired stuff into lexical scope, don't let people touch your global environment without you knowing it.

```
import {Sesssion} from 'api-core';
const Session = require('api-core').session;
```

If you are at the frontend delivering code for the browser you can't use `import` unless you transpile your ES6 code using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/).

Example transpiling using Gulp.js:

```
// $ npm install --save-dev gulp-babel babel-preset-es2015

// gulpfile.js
const gulp  = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
 
gulp.task('transpile', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/app.js')
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// $ gulp transpile
```

**Legacy workaround:**

When using ES6 features is not an option the only workaround to using a bunch of global variables, is using only one, and have hope:

```
// scripts/app.js
var MyApp = {
  globals: {
    foo: "bar",
    fizz: "buzz"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var ASHIVA_HandsOffNHS = (function() {
    
    // VARIABLES

    var my_var = 10;


    // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
    
    function bar() {
        console.log(my_var + 5);
    }


   // PUBLIC OBJECT

    myObject = {};
    
    myObject['a_func'] = function() {
            my_var += 10;
            console.log(my_var);
        };
        
    myObject['b_func'] = function() {
            my_var = 0;
            console.log(my_var);
        };

    return myObject;

})();

ASHIVA_HandsOffNHS.a_func();
ASHIVA_HandsOffNHS.b_func();
ASHIVA_HandsOffNHS.a_func();
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your solution is that it just makes you code harder to understand while still keeping all the downsides of global variables. The page you linked to covers the problems. The only problem your proposed solution really solves is namespace pollution but at the cost of not being able to see what global variables are declared as easily as the declaration is a function call).

The solution is to write code without global variables. If a function needs a value pass it as a argument.

Comment: ... and if an object needs context, supply it as a constructor argument.

Comment: Thank's but in this scenario passing values as arguments would not work. I need various variables that remains persistent and are accessible to several functions.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do this.
As to why see e.g. the top post here:  [What is the most EVIL code you have ever seen in a production enterprise environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434414/what-is-the-most-evil-code-you-have-ever-seen-in-a-production-enterprise-environm/434562#434562)

As a side note, one can always execute "global" code without littering the place with globals:

```js
(function() {
  var notaglobal = 1;
  alert(notaglobal);
})();
//notaglobal is not defined in this scope
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answer most explain with anonymous function as [this](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/) article mention,

> Anonymous functions are difficult to debug, maintain, test, or reuse.

Here are example with normal function. It's easier to read and understand.

```js
/* global variable example */

    var a= 3, b= 6;
    
    function fwithglobal(){
    console.log(a, b); // 3 6 expected
    }
    
    fwithglobal(); // first call
    
    function swithglobal(){
    var a=9;
    console.log(a, b); // not 3 6 but 9 6
    }
    
    swithglobal(); // second call
    

/* global variable alternative(function parameter) */

    function altern(){
    var a= 3, b= 6; // var keyword needed
      f_func(a,b);
      s_func(a,b);
    }
    
    function f_func(n, m){
    console.log(n, m); // 3 6 expected
    }
    
    function s_func(n, m){
    var a=9;
    console.log(n, m); // 3 6 expected
    }
    
    altern(); // only once
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are bad... if left unmanaged!

The potential risks of global variables is as high as the pleasure and productivity gains of having frequently used objects ready to use.

I don't believe one should seek a single alternative. Instead I advocate for one object in charge of managing those globals and as the code base/component matures, refactor them out

One thing not mentioned in the current answers which I think is critical is an understanding of DI and IoC containers. These address many of the problems people try to solve with global variables, but covering related concerns that plain globals can't, like object life cycles.