# Turn a JavaScript local variable into a global variable

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function to generate a variable. That function is activated by an onclick button event.

After that variable is generated, I need to use it as a global variable so that other JavaScript processes can use that variable.

How do I do it?

Comment: FYI,let alone processes, javascript don't even use threads except i think setTimeout

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to add the variable's value to a property of the global `window` object:

```
window.yourVarName = yourVarName;
```

Then the other functions will be able to access `yourVarName` simply by referencing `yourVarname` directly. There will be no need to use `window.yourVarName`.

However keep in mind that in general, [*global variables are evil*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use).

Comment: why is it evil? Mind explain a little?

Comment: @Eric: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use

Comment: in Javascript, by default it is windows object,why  again prefixing it with window

Comment: @Srinivas: Primarily clarity, to avoid the horror of implicit globals.

Comment: @Srinivas makes the assignment clearer, not including it would make it ambiguous were that variable is declared.

Comment: @Srinivas: Because if I understood the OP's context correctly, the variable `yourVarname` will be defined in local function scope as well.

Comment: If you assign a variable inside local function scope without the `var` keyword, it gets assigned to the window object (in FF at least) so the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @roryf: Yes true. But I think the OP had it as a local variable. It could be a function argument for example.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable outside the scope of the function:

```
var foo = null;

function myClickEvent() {
    foo = someStuffThatGetsValue;
}
```

Better yet, use a single global variable as the namespace ("MyApp") for your application, and store the value inside that:

```
var MyApp = {
    foo: null
};

function myClickEvent() {
    MyApp.foo = someStuffThatGetsValue;
}
```

The function itself could even be included in there.