# JavaScript and local variables bad practise?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad to use local variable in the code below and if so, why?

```
var lib = new function () {

    var localVariable;

    this.publicCall = function (e) {
      localVariable = e.variable;
    };

    var privateCall = function (e) {
      localVariable = e.variable; 
    };
};
```

Comment: no, why would it be bad?  it's a way to do private vars in JS

Comment: @Javier Thank God for local variables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in fact I'd say that looks like good practice.

What alternative were you thinking of? A global variable? Now *that* would be bad practice.

Comment: hmm, most times I can pass variable by injecting it into the arguments of a function I'm calling, thus using arguments as a main transport, it just looks less readable than using local vars...

Comment: Injection is good if it's preventing a dependency (ie because it makes unit testing easier), but for simple variables, there's no dependency to worry about, so no real need to inject everything. A local variable is fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is actually a preferred pattern. Local variables should always be defined in the scope in which they needed. You definitely shouldn't pollute your global scope with variables as this is considered a bad practice.

There are many resources on the web to help you understand variable scope. Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613647/56864).