# Implement Sencha Touch ListPaging plugin

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a simple Sencha Touch contacts/users app, which shows a list and then discloses more details.

I reach my server with Ext.Ajax.request using our API to fetch the users and populate the list. However, the totalcount is usually above 500, so I need to implement the ListPaging plugin. For security reasons, I am pretty sure I cannot do the "proxy" method (because I have to use a "token" for authenticating requests). Maybe I am wrong; documentation is sparse, so I need a boost.

My server returns the following:

```
    data: [,…]
    hasnextpage: true
    haspreviouspage: false
    pageindex: 0
    pagesize: 9999
    success: true
    totalcount: 587
    totalpages: 14
```

My Store:

```
     Ext.define('MyApp.store.StudentStore',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        config:{
           storeId: 'Students', 
           model:'MyApp.model.people',
           autoLoad:false,
           remoteFilter:true,      //just trying stuff I've read about
           sortOnFilter:true,
           clearOnPageLoad: false,
           grouper: {
                 groupFn: function(record) {
                   return record.get('lastname')[0];
                 }
           },
           sorters: 'lastname'
        }
    });
```

And my List View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    alias : 'widget.mainPanel',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.StudentStore',
        'Ext.plugin.ListPaging'
    ],

    config: {
        store : 'Students',
        model: 'people',
        grouped:true,
        sorters: 'lastname',
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">'+                    
                    '<h1>{firstname:ellipsis(45)} {lastname:ellipsis(45)}</h1>' +
                    '<h4>{grade} grade</h4>' +
                '</tpl>'
        ),
        plugins: [{
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true,
            bottom: 0,
            loadMoreText: ''
        }]           
    }
});
```

I would like to utilize the ListPaging plugin to autoload the next 45 users when the screen is scrolled to the bottom. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT : SOLVED!!**

@arthurakay -- you were right, my "token" was definitely getting clobbered up at some point.. 
Since my API requires a token for every request, I was able to create a "beforeload" function in which I set my proxy, with the token I received on login -- before the ListPaging needs to be called. So, by the time the user is ready to scroll and activate ListPaging, my token is stored with the first record I received from the server, and magically adds 50 more records each time the user scrolls to the bottom.

I really hope this helps someone!!

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.PersonStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config:{
        storeId: 'Persons',
        model:'MyApp.model.PersonModel',
        autoLoad:false,
        clearOnPageLoad: true,

        listeners: {
            beforeload: function(store){

                store.setProxy({
                    headers: {
                        Accept : 'application/json',
                        Authorization : 'Bearer:' + this.token
                    },
                    type: 'ajax',
                    pageParam: 'pageindex',
                    url: this.url,
                    extraParams: {
                        count: this.count
                    },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty:'data',
                        pageParam: 'pageindex',
                        totalProperty: 'totalcount'
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(record) {
                return record.data.lastname[0]
            }
        },
        sorters: 'lastname'
    },

    setParams: function(params){
        for (var prop in params){
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                this[prop] = params[prop];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And I add the 'setParams' while adding the items to the store here:

```
        var feedStore = Ext.getStore('FeedStore');

        //call the setParams method that we defined in the store
        feedStore.setParams({
            token: TOKEN,
            count: 50,
            url: URL
        });
```

Comment: can you give details why proxiy can not be used here ?

Comment: @phazorRise because I am using an API method to return the data, the url I declare in the proxy will not match my application url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the API docs are "sparse"?

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.plugin.ListPaging

From the very top:

*"By specifying autoPaging: true, an 'infinite scroll' effect can be achieved, i.e., the next page of content will load automatically when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list."*

Also, what does security have to do with using the proxy? If you have to pass the token in each request, use the "extraParams" config on the store proxy:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams

Comment: Thanks, that's the direction I am heading, but I'm having an issue storing my token as a global variable. I declare it in app.js as window.token and when I add the token to my extraParams, the inspector reads "undefined". Even though when I type "token" in the console, it returns the correct data.

Comment: Perhaps the global "token" variable is getting clobbered at some point - or perhaps it needs to be JSON encoded when sending it to the server. Could be a lot of possibilities here, but without seeing the actual code it's hard to say.

Comment: Actually you can define the variable in app.js by declaring it just before `Ext.application()`. That will give you global variable which can be accessed anywhere in application BUT Global Variables are BAD (Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)