# Variable data How to send thourgh ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I sent the variable data through ajax loading_add.php page an error 
is displayed:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: profit is not defined.

What I tried so far is attached below.

```
var profit = (
  Number($("#pro_price").val() - retail_price)
);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '../php/product/loading_add.php',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {
      profit: profit
  };
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to help if you don't post your server side code.

Comment: Is this your real code? If it is - it has a syntax error.

Comment: error on which side? js or php?

Comment: Try to debug: what does the profit variable return? If its NAN try to add parseInt and check

Comment: function profit () {
        var profit = (
           Number($("#pro_price").val() - retail_price )
    );
        
        console.log(profit );
    }
});         here output diplayed success

Comment: Obviously you had an error in your JS code, try to figure out where your variable had been created and changed before AJAX request

Comment: @ProgrammerHari Are you making your AJAX request in the same function?

Comment: @ProgrammerHari Seems like you trying to get `profit` out of it's scope. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you php page just define variable as:

```
@$_POST['profit'];
```

you will not get undefined error again, hope this trick will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

But I share the valid way to send data via AJAX and retrieve the data in PHP Server Side..

```
var profit = (
    Number($("#pro_price").val() - retail_price)
);

console.log(profit); // see in console log if `profit` is a valid variable or not
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../php/product/loading_add.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        profit: profit
    }
}).done(function(result){
    //do something after done AJAX
});
```

In server side, you must call variable `$_POST['profit']` to retrieve the `profit` value.

Comment: i tried  sir Uncaught ReferenceError: profit is not defined

Comment: If you follow my code, there's nothing wrong at all.. maybe there's something wrong in your actual code.... let's try to put hardcode value on `profit`... `data: {profit: 23)`... see if it works...

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: profit is not defined .  ajex error sir

Comment: profit: 23 if i put like this data successfully goes to the page. how to define the variable sir .  this is doen't work profit: profit

Comment: try `console.log(profit);` before AJAX..and see in DevTools (Console Tab) , what value it'll give...

Comment: out put displayed 5

Comment: maybe your actual code got problem...you can refer to this topic for `undefined variable` issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583544/referenceerror-variable-is-not-defined

Comment: @ProgrammerHari,,, can you share what is the actual problem and what is the solution....and please mark the correct answer ....