# How to use javascript constant in javascript file from another javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have created one javascript file in which I have declared different string constants.

now in another javascript file I want to use those String constants from already created javascript file.

Is there any way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running it in a browser? If yes, just source the second file after the first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you declare your constants in `file1` as global variables:

```
var someConstant = 42;
```

Then you can just use that variable in your other JS files. Just make sure `file1` is loaded before you try to use them.

However, [polluting the global scope like this come with it's risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use), as those variables are easily changed.

Comment: This should not be accepted as answer. We all know global variables are bad, not generic and not neat

Comment: @canbax: Hence that last line in my answer.

Comment: This is not a constant

Comment: @still_dreaming_1: At the time this question was asked (this question is almost ___6 years old___), this was a decent answer. Keep in mind that `const` was first [introduced with ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), in June of 2015. This answer predates the existence of `const`.

Answer (score 8):

Multiple ways.

### Concatenate

Use a task runner like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to define a task that concatenates your files into a single one. This will not only allow convenient definition of constants but also improve performance.

There are other tools to do this, too. See [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) for windows and [codekit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) for Macs.

### Modularize

If you are on client side, use a tool like [require.js](http://requirejs.org) or [browserify](http://browserify.org) to define commonJS / AMD modules and require them as you need.

If you are on server side using node, this works out of the box for commonJS.

### Load scripts in correct order, expose them through global objects.

You could load your constant defining script first and do something like this:

```
var constants = {
    MY_CONST: 'Foo'
}
```

Your main, whi script could access this variable. If you omit the `var` keyword, the variable becomes globally available. Note however that this should be avoided.

You could even add a property to the global object (`window` on the client side).

---

Personally I like to use commonJS modules when working on projects that allow me to do so. [Rob Ashton](http://codeofrob.com/entries/why-i-stopped-using-amd.html) has an opinion on this that I would like to share.

When I can't use those modules in a convenient way, which would be the case when working with (custom) web-components because of their isolated scopes, I like to add a single script which creates
an Object like `App`. I use this object to expose modules, services & constants which can then be required by any component in a neat way:

`App.myService.doSomething()`

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a file which contains all the constants and variables

Constants.js

```
const EMAIL = "xyz@gmail.com"
const PHONE = "9911223344"
var NAME = "Default name"
```

2. Access the Constants.js file in your HTML file

xyz.html

```
<script src="Constants.js"></script>
```

3. Now you can access the Constants in any of file inside a project

Comment: I would import like this: `import { EMAIL } from "./Constants";` in the .js file 
and don't forget, when you attach the script file to the HTML add a `type="module"` like this:
`<script type="module" src="/Constants.js"></script>`