# Calling a constant from another file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm having problems with constants in different files: I have to store an embed in a different file, and then call it in the main one, but when I try to do it gives me parse errors like `Unexpected '.' in 'help.embed'` I tried to use the methods suggested in these threads [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650721/how-to-use-javascript-constant-in-javascript-file-from-another-javascript-file),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)] but they didn't work: it continues to give me that parse error. Can somebody help me?
PS: I don't want to use an HTML file to call the scripts, I want to use only JS and JSON

This is my code (simplified):

```
// help.js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("Title")

module.exports = Object.freeze({
  embed: embed
});
```

```
// main.js
const help = require("./help.js")
client.on("ready", () =>{
  client.channels.find("id",config.disaply_channel).send(help.embed); //Parse error
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the `help` object is coming through properly? Do you see the `embed` property when you log it to the console?

Comment: Try `.send({help.embed})`

Comment: I logged the help object and I clearly see the embed property, with the type RichEmbed. I tried also to log only the help.embed and it's a normal object. But when I tried to send it, it returned "Unable to send empty message"or a thing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if the command was in the same file as the embed I should use `message.channel.send({embed})`, so I tried to send `help.{embed}`, but it gave me a fatal error. 
I resolved declaring the export `embed: {embed}` instead of only `embed: embed`, and then calling `help.embed` in the main file. Thank you for your support anyway