# onclick attribute not working even after the function is defined

Tags: javascript, html, crosswalk

I'm dynamically populating html by using a for loop like this

```
function htmlpopulate() {
  /*some DOM manipulations*/
  setInterval(loadhtml, 5000); //getting live data
}

function loadhtml {
  activediv.innerHTML = '';
  for (i = 0; i < userarray.length; i++) {
    var temp = userarray[i].trim();
    activediv.innerHTML += '<p onclick="makecall(' + "'" + temp + "'" + ');return false;")">' + temp + '</p><br/>';
  }
}

function makecall(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

output:**makecall is not defined**
how to make the inline function to call that **defined** function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function makecall` must be defined in the global context:

```
window.makecall = function (data) {
  console.log(data);
};
```

Also, you need to sort out quotes and parenthesis in

```
activediv.innerHTML += '<p onclick="makecall(' + "'" + temp + "'" + 
  ');return false;")">' + temp + '</p><br/>';
```

you don't need **)"** after **return false;"**.

Comment: its too a type dude! `window.makecall` is a useful resource

Comment: @PhaneendraCharyuluKanduri - I don't understand.What is "its too a type dude"?

Comment: i've said that its a typing mistake. in a friendly manner :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/vxbwx8qb/8/) representing dynamically created buttons with click function.

You can also try this if you are not able to bind function:

```
document.getElementById("btnID").onclick = makeCall;
```

#### Code

```js
function createHTML(){
    var div = document.getElementById("content");
    var _html = "";
 for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
     _html += "<button onclick='notify("+i+")'>btn " + i +"</button>";
    }
    div.innerHTML = _html;
}

function notify(str){
 console.log("Notify" + str);
}


function print(data) {
 console.log(data);
}

function registerEvent(){
    var btnList = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
 document.getElementById("btnID").onclick = function(){ print(btnList) };
}

(function(){
 createHTML();
    registerEvent();
})()
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="btnID">BTN ID</button>
```

Comment: what is `btnTest` in `document.getElementById("btnTest").onclick = function(){ print(btnList)};`

Comment: Sorry! its a typo. It should be `btnID`. I'll update my answer

Comment: how is `notify()` working over there in `JSFiddle`. if it does i dont have to ask this question(im working on `android-crosswalk`) and another 2. i have to pass different argument for each button, to recieve unique argument for representing that button, help

Comment: @PhaneendraCharyuluKanduri, [update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/vxbwx8qb/8/) with passing flag to `notify()`. Also try *loading js after DOM* is rendered. You can simulate on JSFiddle. Change JS load type to `onLoad` from body and these will not work. Hope it helps. Also I have updated my answer to show same

Comment: its so cool.
global decleration `window.function_name` has worked as said by @Igor

Comment: Ideally, you should avoid using global scope. It is considered as bad practice. You can refer following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There, you're defining `makecall()`,  but you need to actually call it afterward, like so:

`makecall(the data you want to use);`