# javascript : get a global variable from its name as string (reflection)

Tags: javascript, reflection

I saw a lot of answer to call a method from a given object using a string, but no one to get the object itself.
I would like something like that

```
var a
var b
var c

function getObject(objectAsString)
{
return getMyObject(objectAsString);
}
```

then if I write

```
var obj=getObject("a")
```

my result is obj=a

Is there a function "getMyObject"?
Thanks

Comment: if it's a global variable, you can do window[ string ]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
var hello = 'Hello World';
this['hello'];
```

I wouldn't make those variables so global though. [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)
Instead put them inside an object like:

```
var obj = {
   a: 'Hello',
   b: 'World'
}
console.log(obj['a'], obj['b']);
```

Answer (score 2):

See following code

```
<script>
//in one script
var GlobalvarName = 500;

alert(window["GlobalvarName"]); //alert is : 500

</script>
```