# Function doesnt work when variables are first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got into weird problem, here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".switch-content div:first-child").fadeIn();
    $(".switch-content div:first-child").toggleClass("switch-active");
    $(".switch-menu ul li").click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).parent().find("li.switch-active").toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div.switch-active").fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div.switch-active").toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div:nth-child("+clicked+")").delay(200).toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div:nth-child("+clicked+")").delay(200).fadeIn();
    });

})
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
var linked = $("#"+anchor).index()+1;
```

**^ this works**

When my code is like this, everything works fine, but when I move variables on first spot, my javascript stops working.

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
var linked = $("#"+anchor).index()+1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".switch-content div:first-child").fadeIn();
    $(".switch-content div:first-child").toggleClass("switch-active");
    $(".switch-menu ul li").click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).parent().find("li.switch-active").toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div.switch-active").fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div.switch-active").toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div:nth-child("+clicked+")").delay(200).toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div:nth-child("+clicked+")").delay(200).fadeIn();
    });
```

**^ this doesnt work**

Does anyone know why? It makes no sense to me. And I know that my code could be simplier, I'm working on it. :)

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Have you checked console for any errors?

Comment: I have checked the console and there was nothing unusual, also what do you mean by closest, Thank you. :)

Comment: instat of parent().parent().parent() use closest() and your variable linked may be null if the page hasn't loaded completely

Comment: You use hash that why its give you null

Comment: I will use .closest, looks better for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because it's outside the $(document).ready()

The browser will load that function first when the page loads leaving the variables out of the function which would mean their value would be null.

To get it as a global do:

```
var Foo = {};

$(document.ready(function() {
    Foo.anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    Foo.linked = $("#"+anchor).index()+1;
    // rest of code
});
```

Comment: I guess either way, those variables would be global variables and will be called before document.ready. If one is working fine, other should work as well

Comment: I need to have these two as global variable.

Comment: @Kyrbi for your reference [global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)

Answer (score 0):

I think the below part of code is breaking

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
var linked = $("#"+anchor).index()+1;
```

Please check the console. The substring might have returned some value and jquery is not able to find the DOM element. Once a javascript error occurs, the remaining part of the code will not get executed.
Console errors will help you to know the root cause

Comment: This should be a comment. Also, OP has already confirmed that there is no errors in console.

Comment: I agree with you Rajesh, as i started typing the answer. By the time I submitted, there were comments shown

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my problem. I was looking for something before the document was loaded. So this is how I fixed it.

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
var linked = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
    linked = $("#"+anchor).index()+1;
    $(".switch-content div:first-child").fadeIn();
    $(".switch-content div:first-child").toggleClass("switch-active");
    $(".switch-menu ul li").click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).parent().find("li.switch-active").toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div.switch-active").fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div.switch-active").toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div:nth-child("+clicked+")").delay(200).toggleClass("switch-active");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".switch-content div:nth-child("+clicked+")").delay(200).fadeIn();
    });
})
```

Thank you guys for helping me realize my mistake. :)