# Pull value from a function within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `map` element that has multiple `areas`, and user can select one of those. Each `area` has an `ID` that represents a number (which I need to use in an equation later on).

How do I store the `ID` of selected `area` in a variable for later use?

My work so far:

```
function areaSelection(){
$("map").on('click', 'area', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var areaSelect = parseInt(this.id);


console.log(areaSelect);
});

}

var mapSelection = areaSelection();

$("area").on('click', areaSelection);
```

Comment: Create the variable outside of the `areaSelection` function. See **'function scope'** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: Why not the areaSelect variable is a global variable?

Comment: How about a `variable`?

Comment: Never use global variables. Firstly, you're assigning a function call to a variable, which is returning `undefined`. Secondly, the `areaSelection` function only creates the click event. It doesn't actually calculate the `areaSelect` value.

Answer (score 2):

#### Do your best to never use global variables.

**Firstly**, you're assigning a function call to a variable, which is returning undefined (all functions do this unless the return statement is used).

**Secondly**, the `areaSelection` function only creates the click event.
It doesn't actually calculate the `areaSelect` value.

---

Instead try something like this:

```
var mapSelection;

$("map").on('click', 'area', areaSelection);

function areaSelection(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mapSelection = parseInt(this.id);
}
```

This way, the `mapSelection` is getting set any time the `map` is clicked, **but be aware that this is not likely to be efficient**.

Comment: Bonus points for you! This did the trick! May I ask, why is it inefficient?

Comment: Not sure... there may be something you're calculating on click. The code I provided is not likely to be that inefficient. _(I was trying to cover my butt if someone found a massive issue with the code)_

Comment: @4castle - in personal projects where all code is written by you? none. Otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613647/989920

Comment: @4castle - In little toy projects where all code is written by you globals _might_ be ok. Little. Toy. Projects. In anything of _any_ significant size global variables will likely lead to unintended side-effects as various bits of code read and write values on the global, even if you are the only coder. Encapsulation is key; code should be unaffected by things outside that code. Discussion of this is everywhere, in books, tutorials, web articles, etc.; it is an extremely basic concept in program design.