# How to add varible on to it self

Tags: javascript, html

In the code I'm trying to add plus on to a variable that it self can I can't see where I'm going wrong:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>The * Operator</h1>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var playerscore = playerscore + 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = playerscore;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First declare (`var playerscore`) and then assign new value (`playerscore = playerscore + 1;`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `playerscore` and set it to an initial value, probably 0 in this case. Like this:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
  var playerscore = 0;

  function myFunction() {
    playerscore = playerscore + 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = playerscore;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The OP may also benefit from knowing that an alternative (shorthand) way to write `playerscore = playerscore + 1;` is `playerscore++;`

Answer (score 1):

in your function `playerscore` only exists inside the function. So it will initally be `undefined`. The easiest ([though not necessarily the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)) is to define the variable in the [global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

```
//outside of function now in global scope (or window.playerscore)
//set it to a value (0) also. Otherwise it's undefined. undefined +1 is not going to work
var playerscore = 0;
function myFunction() {
   //no var, the varibale is declared above NOT in here Important!
   playerscore = playerscore + 1;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = playerscore;
}
```

---

and even better option is to use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work):

```
var myModule = (function(document){
     //no longer in global scope. Scoped inside myModule so not publically accessible
     var playerscore = 0;

     function myFunction() {
        //no var, the varibale is declared above NOT in here Important!
        playerscore = playerscore + 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = playerscore;
     }

     //allow myFunction to be called externally
     return{myFunction:myFunction};
})(document);
```

HTML changed for the above:

```
<button onclick="myModule.myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

though this may be a little too advanced at the moment. If your interested in the above I reccmoend reading about the [The Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the variable `palyerscore` before initializing it. As a result it will be undefined and incrementing a non-initialized variable is pointless and hence you won't be seeing anything on the screen.

So, replace

```
var playerscore = playerscore + 1;
```

before the `myFunction()` put:

```
var playerscore = 0;
```

then inside `myFunction` put:

```
playerscore = playerscore + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, my understanding was wrong. What I thought is the user wants to increment it only once.