# Not able to access the value in one method in other

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I would like to insert the value here as to send the JSON to backend but unable to get it.

```
var generateSearchObject = function() {
    var searchObj = {
        "fileName": change, // Here the fileName should be "Change Data"
        "tabType": text.toUpperCase(),
        "offset": offValue,
    };
    return searchObj;
};
var renderCrumbs = function(breadCrumbs, state, node) {
    var change = "Change Data";
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all `renderCrumbs: function(breadCrumbs, state, node) { ... }` makes no sense, because you're using `Object` property notation with no Object to be found. If it is contained within an `Object` which is not visible in the code snippet then all is fine, but keep in mind that you must reference the object to call the function in the following code snippet, e.g. `obj.renderCrumbs()`.

Secondly, and problematically, you may be tempted to use `change` as a global. Don't do this, globals are bad. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use). Further information is available elsewhere with a little googling.

The best solution that I can see is to change the functionality of `renderCrumbs` to

```
function renderCrumbs(breadCrumbs, state, node) {
    return 'Change Data';
}
```

and then you can do

```
var generateSearchObject = function() {
   var searchObj = {
       "fileName": renderCrumbs(), 
       "tabType": text.toUpperCase(),
       "offset": offValue,
   };
   return searchObj;
};
```

Comment: If you did all that I said then I'll need more code to see where the issue is.

Comment: As I said, change `renderCrumbs: ...` to `function renderCrumbs() { ... }`, and avoid global variables like the plague. Here's a working version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/5e2hq95y/7/. You'll be able to see the object logged in the console.

Comment: Pls do using global just for example

Comment: `renderCrumbs: function () { ... }` is not valid JavaScript. Why do you want globals?

Comment: It will never work as long as you use `renderCrumbs: function () { ... }`