# How to give a local variable, a global scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

Below code snippet is `Drift chat` method to get the `email id` provided by user in chat.

I am trying to access `email id (e.data.email)` outside of given function scope by storing it in a global variable `data_email`.

I have tried `three` method to make `data_email` global variable - `window`, `let`, `const`.

```
window.drift.on("emailCapture", function(e) {
    console.log("user identified as: " + e.data.email);

    window.data_email = e.data.email;
    // let data_email = e.data.email;
    // const data_email = e.data.email;

    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'driftemail',
        eventAction: 'driftemailCaptured',
    });
});

console.log(data_email);
```

After trying all that I am getting error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: data_email is not defined`.
Please anyone suggest me a work around, i will be very thankful. My goal is to access captured email outside of the given function.

Comment: Did the event fire before you try to retrieve the value?

Comment: after firing event and email is getting captured inside function - `console.log("user identified as: " + e.data.email);`  but the same error is coming for outside variable

Comment: Declare it BEFORE the event handler, then it will have global scope - and use `let` or `var` not `const`

Comment: ?? But you're trying to log `e.data.email`, not `data_email`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem you have there is the fact you are listening to an event. That can happen now, later or never. However you immediately try to console log it.

Given the small amount of information you provided, there could be various solutions to your problem. But one solution is to make:

- outside function, that function accepts email and sets it as global
- call that function with email as argument

Something like this

```
window.drift.on("emailCapture", function(e) {
    console.log("user identified as: " + e.data.email);

    setChatEmail(e.data.email);

    //window.data_email = e.data.email;
    //let data_email = e.data.email;
    //const data_email = e.data.email;

    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'driftemail',
        eventAction: 'driftemailCaptured',
    });
});


function setChatEmail(email) {
  window.data_email = email;
}
```

Further reading:

How to [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function) global variable.

Why are [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use) variables bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your console.log runs before "emailCapture" event is executed. Thats why its giving you undefined, try everything what you want to do after executing this event.

```
 var data_email;
 var getEmail = function() {
     console.log(data_email);
 };
 window.drift.on("emailCapture", function(e) {
    console.log("user identified as: " + e.data.email);

    window.data_email = e.data.email;
    data_email = e.data.email;
    // const data_email = e.data.email;

    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'driftemail',
        eventAction: 'driftemailCaptured',
    });
    getEmail();
});
```

Comment: In your example, how is callbackFunc a call back function? Clearly it is not. Either change the function name so it does not insinuates, or make it a callback.

Comment: Didn't understand your question

Comment: Function you say is a callback. It is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `window.data_email` on top first then mutate it. Because the `console.log` will run before it's initialized.

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet for doing the same as your answer

Comment: like what @Jefree Sujit answer does