# how to make a variable global only in one place

Tags: php

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);

function abc(){
    global $db;
    ...
}

function xyz(){
    global $db;
    ...
}
```

Let's say I have 100 functions which uses `$db`.

Is it the true that I must `100 times` write `global $db`?

Is there a way to access `$db` in all functions automatically, like in javascript?

Comment: Why don't you have a `class` for all your stuff?

Comment: @SahilGulati, write a class is reasonable if you have a lot of job you need to centralize, buto not just because declare a variable global, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far I know, there no way to do such thing, you need to declare `global $db` in every function you wanna use it

Comment: @bonaca it's a restriction, a feature. If they allow developers to use global variables inside function scope or class scope without the keyword 'global', there is a high chance we (developers) would mix between local scope variables and global variables

Comment: javascript solved this very simply: global variables inside a function is accessed by writing without `var`.

Comment: @bonaca Client-side language != Server-side language. No comparisons. Read the updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667849/5447994)

Comment: Difference between `server side` and `client side` is just about execution platform.I think - there is no reason to limit variable access in a language just because it's a `server-side`.

Comment: @bonaca every language has its ups and downs, and every language has its own way of how to handle specific things, like this question for example. If we will compare languages about this question, we will no-doubt find that every language handles this question differently

Comment: I would say that this `variable stuff` is a php's `very deep down` and I'm waiting someone to say that clearly.

Comment: @bonaca In JS, it's easier/shorter than PHP by a line, but it's also extremely easy to go into hell of a nightmare by mistakenly overwriting global variables. And because of this, [there are hundreds of topics why it's bad & evil to declare global variables/methods and how to avoid them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613647/134824).

Answer (score 1):

You can otherwise use super global `$GLOBALS['db']` directly inside your function without the need to declare every time.

Only for this reason we use [Object Oriented Approach](http://www.w3programmers.com/crud-with-pdo-and-oop-php/) or some libraries like [medoo](https://medoo.in/).

---

**Update:** *(From one of your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667803/how-to-make-a-variable-global-only-in-one-place/45667849#comment-78293229))*

You nay need to understand the [Scope of the Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/5447994) to know its advantage before calling so.

Comment: but writing `$GLOBALS['db']` is even more then writing `global $db`.

Comment: Yes, but declaration prior to its usage inside the function can be skipped. But that is the reason why would I suggest you for some object oriented approach using class

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `$db` as parameter to functions or use `$GLOBALS['db']`

```
function abc($db){
    $db->query();
}
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['db'] = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
function abc (){
   $GLOBALS['db']->query();
}
```

Comment: but writing `$GLOBALS['db']` is even more then writing `global $db`.

Answer (score 1):

If need to access variable, then yes, you have to add global in all your functions or use $_GLOBALS

since you are using function, better to create static class

```
class DB {
   private static $db       = null;
   public static function connect() {
     if(!empty(self::$db)) {
       return self::$db;
     }
     self::$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    }
}
```

Access db using DB::connect()->query();

Comment: Thanks but... all this job for just to declare a variable accessible!

Comment: cool... we can also declare db as constant and  can use it in all functions.. I never tried :)

Answer (score 1):

As everyone already said, you have to use the keyword `global` to avoid mixing with local variables:

```
function my_func() {
    global $db;
    ...
}
```

If you really need a global variable, one possible way is to use the `$_GLOBALS`:

```
$_GLOBALS['db'] = $db;    

function my_func() {
    $_GLOBALS['db']->...;
    ...
}
```

It's better to use OOP, but sometimes, a developer needs to write a quick script that do stuff, and PHP is a good choice for this. If you don't want to go OOP-way and still want to use global variables in many functions, here's a workaround.

1- Create a file, let's call it my_globals.php that has this content:

```
// my so many globals stay here
global $db;
global $a;
global $b;
...
```

2- In your main file, you would do something like this:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$a = ...;
$b = ...;

function abc(){
    include 'my_globals.php';// this will be equivalent as typing all your global variables
    ...
}

function xyz(){
    include 'my_globals.php';// this will be equivalent as typing all your global variables
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's much simpler to write `global $db` each time.

Comment: True. I suggested this workaround if you have **many** global variables, in that case, in every function, you will to write multiple of `global $var`