# Loop changing background color with switch in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, global-variables

So I've been trying to make this switch, it's simple in my head. stating a variable "num" equaling 1 to begin with, setting an "if" or "while" statement for when "num" is equal to 2, the background color of a certain div will change from white to yellow and back in .5 second intervals. My problem I THINK is that I can't seem to change the global variable. I've changed it to 2, and the loop worked, but when it's 1 and I try to use the button to change to 2, nothing happnes! Here's the JS I have so far:

```
var num = 1;
document.getElementById("numberDisplay").innerHTML = num;
if (num == 2) {
  var flash = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  function timer() {
    document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    setTimeout(white, 500);
    function white() {
      document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay").innerHTML = num;
}
document.getElementById("buttonOne").onclick=function(){num = 1;}
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").onclick=function(){num = 2;}
```

edit: 1/30/2018 12:25pm
Really appreciate the help guys! A friend of mine actually gave me some advice, that was using window.onload and event timers! Here's what I came up with:

```
   var num = 1;

   window.onload = function(){
    var button1 = document.getElementById("buttonOne")
    var button2 = document.getElementById("buttonTwo")
    button1.addEventListener("click",function(){
        num = 2;
    })
    button2.addEventListener("click",function(){
        num = 1;
    })
    setInterval(checkNum, 1000);
   }

   function checkNum() {
    if (num == 2) {
            document.getElementById("buttonOne").style.backgroundColor = "#ccccb3";
            document.getElementById("buttonTwo").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.getElementById("lightChanger").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            setTimeout(grey, 500);
            function grey() {
            document.getElementById("lightChanger").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
                }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("lightChanger").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").style.backgroundColor = "#ccccb3";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sidney regarding #2, isn't it called with `setInterval`? @TylerLancaster - you should also call `clearInterval` sometime

Comment: If you fix your indentation things will be much clearer both for you and for any who would help you.

Comment: I think you need to have that `if` condition inside the `timer` function

Comment: @Adelin good point. I looked at the code at least three times but missed it every time. That's what I get for not using Ctrl + F. Deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed something:

```js
(function(){
 var changeColor = function(num) {
  document.getElementById("numberDisplay").innerHTML = num;
  if (num === 2) {
     var flash = setInterval(timer, 1000);
     function timer() {
       document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
       setTimeout(white, 500);
       function white() {
          document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "white";
       }
     } 
    } else {
     document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "white";
     document.getElementById("numberDisplay").innerHTML = num;
  }
 }
 
 document.getElementById("buttonOne").addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  let num = 1;
  changeColor(num);
 });
 document.getElementById("buttonTwo").addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  let num = 2;
  changeColor(num);
 });
})();
```

```html
<div id="numberDisplay"></div>
<div id="colorChanger">Color</div>
<button id="buttonOne">1</button>
<button id="buttonTwo">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setInterval, you can use the `timer` function directly inside click handler, and your `timer` function like,

```
var colorChanger = document.getElementById("colorChanger");
function white() {
  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function timer(n) {
  num = n;
  if (num == 2) {
    colorChanger.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    setTimeout(white, 500);
    return;
  }
  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

try this,

---

```js
var num = 1;
var colorChanger = document.getElementById("colorChanger");


function white() {
  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function timer(n) {
  num = n;
  if (num == 2) {
    colorChanger.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    setTimeout(white, 500);
    return;
  }
  colorChanger.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

document.getElementById("buttonOne").onclick = function() {
  timer(1);
}
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").onclick = function() {
  timer(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="colorChanger">switch</div>


<button id='buttonOne'>1</button>
<button id='buttonTwo'>2</button>
```

Comment: As an optimization, you can create a function that takes color and sets it to element. This would reduce code a bit

Answer (score 0):

> but when it's 1 and I try to use the button to change to 2, nothing happnes!

Because, on click, you are changing a variable. This will not trigger anything unless it is observable. You will have to wrap related code a function and call it instead.

```js
function timer(n) {
  function updateBackground(color) {
    document.getElementById("colorChanger").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
  var colors = ['white', 'yellow'];
  updateBackground(colors[n - 1]);
  if (n === 2) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      updateBackground('white')
    }, 500);
  }
}

document.getElementById("buttonOne").onclick = function() {
  timer(1);
}
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").onclick = function() {
  timer(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="colorChanger">switch</div>


<button id='buttonOne'>1</button>
<button id='buttonTwo'>2</button>
```

Few improvements,

- Any variable that is not in a function becomes a part of global scope. You should avoid it.
- I would suggest avoiding `.onclick`. If I fetch the element and replace it with my function, it will break your code. Always prefer using `.addEventListener`. This is opinionated though.
- You should use classes instead of setting individual style. It keeps code clean and maintainable.

```js
function timer(n) {
  if (n === 2) {
    document.getElementById("colorChanger").classList.add("yellow");
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("colorChanger").classList.remove("yellow");
    }, 500);
  }
}

document.getElementById("buttonOne").onclick = function() {
  timer(1);
}
document.getElementById("buttonTwo").onclick = function() {
  timer(2);
}
```

```css
.white {
  background: white;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  /* This is for demo purpose only */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="colorChanger" class='white'>switch</div>


<button id='buttonOne'>1</button>
<button id='buttonTwo'>2</button>
```

#### References:

- [I've Heard Global Variables Are Bad, What Alternative Solution Should I Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)
- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)