# cancel both - parent and child function inside the child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simplified version of the problem.

Clicking on the `button` I need to call `function abc` and stop to execution both functions `abc and click` if `x == 5`;

Current situation - `abc` is canceled, but `click` continues to execute.

```js
function abc(){
if(x == 5){return;}
console.log('abc');
}

var x = 5;

$('button').on('click', function(){
abc();
console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the `console.log('clicked');` to run?

Comment: @Liam, yes, but it should be decided inside `abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you just need to return a result from `abc` and test for it:

```js
function abc(){
  if(x == 5){
    return false;
  }
  console.log('abc');
  return true;
}

var x = 5;

$('button').on('click', function(){
    if (abc()){
       console.log('clicked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

BTW you should [avoid defining global variables (`x`) like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use). Instead use a closure to define a scoped variable. Something more like:

```js
var closure = function(){
  function abc(){
     if(x == 5){
        return false;
     }
     console.log('abc');
     return true;
   }

  var x = 5;
  
  return {abc:abc};
}();

$('button').on('click', function(){
    if (closure.abc()){
       console.log('clicked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

This is called the [Revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Comment: what is the purpose of `closure`, pls?

Comment: Read the [link I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use) in the answer and also the [link in that question](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) @puerto

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to stopping the click from performing any further unwanted actions (for example to stop a form submitting if your button was a "submit" button in a form, or to stop a link from actually visiting the URL of the link), you'd want to use the event's `preventDefault()` method:

```
function abc() {
    console.log('abc');
}


$('button').on('click', function(e){
    if(x == 5) {
        e.preventDefault();
        abc();
    }
    console.log('clicked');
});

var x = 5;
```