# Async function returns a promise.How to make the promise value global?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a async function which returns a promise. I'm confused to how I access the Promise value. I came across `.then()`. It works with `.then()`, but I want to make the promise value global. Which isn't possible if i use `.then()`.

Here is my code:

```
async function getUser() {  
  try {    
    response = await axios.post('/',data);  
  } 
  catch (error) {   
    console.error(error);  
  }  
  return response.data;
}

var global = getUser(); 
console.log(global);
```

This code here returns a promise like so:

[image: screenshot function return value]

I'm wondering how can I access the Promise value (which we can see in the image) and make it global? I'm new to JavaScript unable to wrap my head around async functions.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `var global = await getUser();`

Comment: await can be used only inside a async function right ?Moritz Roessler

Comment: if u notice var global is outside the async function

Comment: @EaGLE Right! Just wrap your call in an async iife. `(async () => {var global = await getUser();})()`

Comment: Using `async`/`await` means you can write code in a synchronous way again, without callbacks and the like. The "downside" is that once you enter into the async code, you can never leave it again. Which means that if you store the result of an async call in a global variable, you can only reliably access it in the same async context. Outside you'll get only the Promise. To put it simpler: `console.log(global)` is called *before* the axios call finishes, not after.

Comment: But then again variable "global" will not have a global scope

Comment: Yes @Chris G.So at the end of the day.it is not possible to make a async function value global?

Comment: It is absolutely possible. You can set a global variable to the result of some `await` call for instance. Then you need to make sure the variable is only accessed *after* the call has finished. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eLcbpvfh/ It all depends on how you're going to use the variable, or rather: *when*.

Comment: I saw your example.Can you please explain how that would translate to my code?

Comment: You are storing the promise in a global variable perfectly fine already. All you need to do is to consume its value using `global.then(data => console.log(data))` instead of `console.log(global)`

Comment: I want to make "data" accessable in a global scope.Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe if you shared why you want it global, we can explain an alternative solution to your objective. Using the result of a promise globally is not possible in a clean way.

Comment: @EaGLE Possible, yes, but pointless, because noone who wants to use the data would know when/whether it already has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Using `async` means your function actually wraps a promise around it. So `global` in `var global = getUser()` is a promise. You can either **await in in an async function** or use `.then()`.

If you want the code to **look** synchronous, you could have a main function, and just call main 'globally':

```
async function main() {
   // because main is an async function, it can unwrap the promise
   const user = await getUser();
   console.log({user});
}

main();
```

You should not try to use `user` 'globally', and only use it in `main`. This is because the promise of getUser might not even be done yet, so it would be unresolved promise. You should only use it when you explicitly waited (`await` or `then`'d) the promise. Also, global variables are not great in any programming language, including [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use).

Comment: I understand your answer perfectly.But my doubt is that how can i make 'user' global.So that i can access it outside the main() function?

Comment: By `main` here, I mean its wraps your entire application/ code. Nothing should be called globally, except `main()`. Just stick everything in `main()`. If you have other files, import/ require them in this file, and use them in `main` or functions that are called in `main`

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `global` value like so:

```
var global;
getUser().then(user => global = user);
```

```js
function getUser() {
  return Promise.resolve("User #1");
}

var global;
getUser().then(user => global = user);

console.log("1", global);
setTimeout(() => console.log("2", global), 500);
```

However keep in mind that other synchronous code has no idea when the `global` variable is set. The value will be `undefined` until the callback is called. The better option might be what you're already doing:

```
var global = getUser();
```

This way other synchronous code can attach callbacks by doing:

```
global.then(user => {
  // ...
});
```

```js
function getUser() {
  return Promise.resolve("User #1");
}

var global = getUser();

global.then(user => console.log("1", user));
setTimeout(() => {
  global.then(user => console.log("2", user));
}, 500);
```