# How to compare this two variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming. I'm trying to code some kind of scorekeeper in JS.
How can I compare two variables: `pointOne` with `maxScore`?

I want to have something like this:
If `pointOne === maxScore -> Player1` wins and game is over.
Currently, this part of the code cannot compare this variable.

This is my code:

```js
const maxInput = document.querySelector('#number');

maxInput.addEventListener('input', function() {

  let maxScore = number.value;
  maxScore = parseInt(this.value);
  console.log(`Max score is ${maxScore}`);


  // if (pointOne === 3){
  //     console.log("mamy 3!");
  // }
})

function headerUpdate() {
  const header = document.querySelector('h1');
  header.innerText = `${pointOne} to ${pointTwo}`;
}


let pointOne = 0;
let pointTwo = 0;

function addPoints() {
  const buttonClickTrue = document.getElementById('btn_one');
  const buttonClickTrue2 = document.getElementById('btn_two');
  const resetButtonTrue = document.getElementById('btn_reset');

  buttonClickTrue.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pointOne++;
    console.log(`Your score is ${pointOne}`);
    headerUpdate();

  })

  buttonClickTrue2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pointTwo++;
    console.log(`Second score is ${pointTwo}`);
    headerUpdate();

  })

  resetButtonTrue.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
  })

}

addPoints();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #7c86ac;
}

.game-box {
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#tenis {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn_one {
  background-color: green;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

#btn_two {
  background-color: orangered;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

#btn_reset {
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

#number {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-box">
  <img src="./img/tenis_image.jpg" alt="tenis" id="tenis">
  <h2>Score Keeper</h2>
  <h1>0 to 0</h1>
  <h3>Use button bellow to count</h3>
  <p id="max">Playing to</p>
  <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
  <button id="btn_one">+1 Player One</button>
  <button id="btn_two">+1 Player Two</button>
  <button id="btn_reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the accepted answers above, I believe that's a bad practise, especially since he's using the var keyword and populating the global namespace. Read this another Stackoverflow answer and why using global variable is bad ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613647/10233884)). Why not use ES6's const or let. You're using an Event Bus Architecture with this code below, so you're avoiding unnecessary complexity and keeping your code out of global namespace:

```js
// Event Bus Architecture
window.addEventListener('click', Button.bind(this));
window.addEventListener('input', Max.bind(this));

function Button(event) {
    const p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    const p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
    event.path[0].id === "btn_one" ? A(p1, p2) : null;
    event.path[0].id === "btn_two" ? B(p1, p2) : null;
    event.path[0].id === "btn_reset" ? Reset() : null;
}

function A(p1, p2) {
    p1.innerText++;
    console.log(`A score is ${p1.innerText}`);
    headerUpdate(p1, p2);
}
function B(p1, p2) {
    p2.innerText++;
    console.log(`B score is ${p2.innerText}`);
    headerUpdate(p1, p2);
}

function Reset() {
    window.location.reload(true);
}

function Max(event) {
    event.path[0].id === "number" ? MaxValue() : null;
}

function MaxValue() {
    const number = document.getElementById("number");
    let maxScore = number.value;
    maxScore = parseInt(maxScore);
    console.log(`Max score is ${maxScore}`);
}

function headerUpdate(p1, p2) {
    p1.innerText = p1.innerText;
    p2.innerText = p2.innerText;

    const number = document.getElementById("number");
    let maxScore = number.value;
    maxScore = +maxScore;
    const pointOne = +p1.innerText;

    if(pointOne === maxScore) {
        console.log("pointOne wins");
    }
}
```

Try this code:

```js
// Event Bus Architecture
window.addEventListener('click', Button.bind(this));
window.addEventListener('input', Max.bind(this));

function Button(event) {
    const p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    const p2 = document.getElementById("p2");
    event.path[0].id === "btn_one" ? A(p1, p2) : null;
    event.path[0].id === "btn_two" ? B(p1, p2) : null;
    event.path[0].id === "btn_reset" ? Reset() : null;
}

function A(p1, p2) {
    p1.innerText++;
    console.log(`A score is ${p1.innerText}`);
    headerUpdate(p1, p2);
}
function B(p1, p2) {
    p2.innerText++;
    console.log(`B score is ${p2.innerText}`);
    headerUpdate(p1, p2);
}

function Reset() {
    window.location.reload(true);
}

function Max(event) {
    event.path[0].id === "number" ? MaxValue() : null;
}

function MaxValue() {
    const number = document.getElementById("number");
    let maxScore = number.value;
    maxScore = parseInt(maxScore);
    console.log(`Max score is ${maxScore}`);
}

function headerUpdate(p1, p2) {
    p1.innerText = p1.innerText;
    p2.innerText = p2.innerText;

    const number = document.getElementById("number");
    let maxScore = number.value;
    maxScore = +maxScore;
    const pointOne = +p1.innerText;

    if(pointOne === maxScore) {
        console.log("pointOne wins");
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #7c86ac;
}

.game-box {
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#tenis{
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn_one{
    background-color: green;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 30%;
}

#btn_two{
    background-color: orangered;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 30%;
}

#btn_reset{
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 30%;
}

#number{
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="game-box">
        <img src="./img/tenis_image.jpg" alt="tenis" id="tenis">
        <h2>Score Keeper</h2>
        <h1><span id="p1">0</span> to <span id="p2">0</span> </h1>
        <h3>Use button bellow to count</h3>
        <p id="max">Playing to</p>
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" value="0">
        <button id="btn_one">+1 Player One</button>
        <button id="btn_two">+1 Player Two</button>
        <button id="btn_reset">Reset</button>

    </div>
    
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its showing `TypeError: event.path is undefined`

Comment: @TechySharnav I understand your problem. But I think you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613647/10233884

Comment: No, no. I don't have any issue with that. Instead, I am thanking you for pointing that out. But, the answer you posted, shows the above error when run.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Declare the `pointOne` and `pointTwo` vars globally using `var` so that you can access them anywhere in code. I also did same for `maxScore`.

Now I put that if condition,  inside click event listeners for the `playerOne` button. It works for it.

```js
const maxInput = document.querySelector('#number');

let  pointOne = 0;
let  pointTwo = 0;
let maxScore = 0;

maxInput.addEventListener('input', function() {

  maxScore = maxInput.value;
  maxScore = parseInt(maxScore);
  console.log(`Max score is ${maxScore}`);



})


function headerUpdate() {
  const header = document.querySelector('h1');
  header.innerText = `${pointOne} to ${pointTwo}`;
}




function addPoints() {
  const buttonClickTrue = document.getElementById('btn_one');
  const buttonClickTrue2 = document.getElementById('btn_two');
  const resetButtonTrue = document.getElementById('btn_reset');

  buttonClickTrue.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pointOne++;
    console.log(`Your score is ${pointOne}`);
    headerUpdate();
    if (pointOne === maxScore) {
      console.log("mamy 3!");
    }
  })

  buttonClickTrue2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pointTwo++;
    console.log(`Second score is ${pointTwo}`);
    headerUpdate();

  })

  resetButtonTrue.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
  })


}

addPoints();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #7c86ac;
}

.game-box {
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#tenis {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn_one {
  background-color: green;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

#btn_two {
  background-color: orangered;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

#btn_reset {
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

#number {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="game-box">
    <img src="./img/tenis_image.jpg" alt="tenis" id="tenis">
    <h2>Score Keeper</h2>
    <h1>0 to 0</h1>
    <h3>Use button bellow to count</h3>
    <p id="max">Playing to</p>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    <button id="btn_one">+1 Player One</button>
    <button id="btn_two">+1 Player Two</button>
    <button id="btn_reset">Reset</button>

  </div>






  <script src="./app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want to over the game, remove all the event listeners, using `elem.removeEventListener()`.

Comment: I believe that's a bad practise, especially since he's using the var keyword and populating the global namespace. Here's an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66931390/10233884