# How to reduce boilerplate code in Vue 3 Composition API (eg router, store)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

With Vue 3 Composition API, each view needs to have these:

```js
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'


export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter()
        const store = useStore()

        // ...
     }
}
```

Is there a way to declare these somehow just once, pass them to the created app, and simply use them without these declarations inside the app views? With vue2, these were passed when app was initialized, then `this.$store` / `this.$router` simply worked.

An idea with global vars, which can easily cause issues: in `app.vue`, these could be declared once like this:

```js
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
    setup() {
        globalthis.store = useStore()
```

then `store` would work everywhere.

Comment: *then store would work everywhere* - welcome to oldschool JS. This is how it was done previously, and the code was horrible. *Would there be any downsides?* - then an author of some library in use with the same mindset thinks it's a good idea to create `store` global variable, and it becomes a mess. Polluting global scope is a bad practice. I hope somebody can link to a question that explains in detail why it's so. It's not specific to Vue. Polluting `Vue.prototype` in Vue 2 is in the same boat.

Comment: You can try to create another composition API to return a new scoped store and router.

I also have the same idea as @Estus Flask, scoped codes can make it easy to debug. 

global value sometimes you difficult to know when it has been changed by some codes when you have to maintain multiple components.

Comment: Agree that globals can cause issues. Is there a way with vue 3 to pass these to the created app and have them available only inside app views, similar to how vue2 worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component instance is not available in `setup()` because the component has not been created yet, so there's no `this` context in the Composition API to use `this.$store`.

I believe the only way to make the store/router variables available in `setup()` *without any other imports* is to attach them to `window`/`globalThis` as globals (ignoring the [caveats of globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)):

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'
export default createRouter({/*...*/})

// store.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
export default createStore({/*...*/})

// main.js
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

window.$router = router
window.$store = store
```

Note the store and router are still available [in the Options API](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-accessing-store-in-vuex4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FStoreOptionsAPI.vue) and [within the template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-accessing-store-in-vuex4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FStoreInTemplate.vue) as `$store` and `$router`, respectively, with Vuex 4 and Vue Router 4:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ $store.state.myProp }}</div>
  <button @click="$router.back()">Back</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store.state.myProp)
    console.log(this.$router.currentRoute)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Options API alternative too

Answer (score 0):

There is the excellent [AutoImport Plugin](https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-auto-import) maintained by `Anthony Fu` which avoids adding all the imports you need and supports `Eslint` and `TypeScript`.

With it, you will never have to scroll between your logic and your imports anymore, and there will be much less noise to focus on your domain!

It also provides presets for `vue`, `vue-router`, `vueuse` and others.

This is my config in a Quasar project:

```
        AutoImport({
          // targets to transform
          include: [
            /\.[tj]sx?$/, // .ts, .tsx, .js, .jsx
            /\.vue$/,
            /\.vue\?vue/, // .vue
            /\.md$/, // .md
          ],

          // global imports to register
          imports: [
            // presets
            `vue`,
            `vue-router`,
            `@vueuse/core`,
            `quasar`,
            `vue-i18n`,
            // custom
            {
              'quasar': [
                `setCssVar`,
                `colors`,
                `extend`,
                `EventBus`,
                `Notify`,
                `QItemSection`,
              ],
              'dedent': [
                [`default`, `dedent`],
              ],
            },
            {
              from: `vue`,
              imports: [`CSSProperties`],
              type: true,
            },
          ],
          // Enable auto import by filename for default module exports under directories
          defaultExportByFilename: false,

          // Auto import for module exports under directories
          // by default it only scan one level of modules under the directory
          dirs: [
            // './hooks',
            // './composables' // only root modules
            // './composables/**', // all nested modules
            // ...
          ],

          // Filepath to generate corresponding .d.ts file.
          // Defaults to './auto-imports.d.ts' when `typescript` is installed locally.
          // Set `false` to disable.
          dts: `./auto-imports.d.ts`,

          // Auto import inside Vue template
          // see https://github.com/unjs/unimport/pull/15 and https://github.com/unjs/unimport/pull/72
          vueTemplate: false,

          // Custom resolvers, compatible with `unplugin-vue-components`
          // see https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import/pull/23/
          resolvers: [
            /* ... */
          ],

          // Inject the imports at the end of other imports
          injectAtEnd: true,

          // Generate corresponding .eslintrc-auto-import.json file.
          // eslint globals Docs - https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals
          eslintrc: {
            enabled: true, // Default `false`
            filepath: `./.eslintrc-auto-import.json`, // Default `./.eslintrc-auto-import.json`
            globalsPropValue: true, // Default `true`, (true | false | 'readonly' | 'readable' | 'writable' | 'writeable')
          },
        }),
```