# make multiple lighbox in one page with javascript (Lighbox 2& 3 doesnt work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vue.js, lightbox2

ive read and try all tutorial from any site on internet,im rather forgot about javascript because snce for 3 years ago i using javascript,but now im still learn again javascript with their framework.And from many tutorial ive seen one of them site is from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp),from those site tutorial they give example to make one lighbox image on one page.but i wanna make it become three lighbox at once.but the problem come when i change each class name from each lightbox.ive try to make multiple class or id name on js script,but it seems doesnt work.

excpected:
each lighbox shows their own image,but not just image on lighbox1.
[image: lighbox 1,2,3 image on one page]

my trouble:
in lighbox 2 & 3,the image that appears is form lighbox 1.
[image: the image from lighbox 1 appears on lighox 2&3 like this]

and this is my code:

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides","mySlides1");
//   for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
//             slides[i].style.display = "none";
//         }
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo","demo1");
//   for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
//    dots[i].style.display = "block";            
//         }
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption","caption1");
//   for (var i = 0; i < captionText.length; i++) {
//    captionText[i].style.display = "block";            
//         }
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides.mySlides1.mySlides2 {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox1</h2>
<!-- this for lightbox 1 -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end lightbox1 -->
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- this for lighbox2 -->
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox2</h2>
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
   <div class="modal-content">
 
     <div class="mySlides1">
       <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides1">
       <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides1">
       <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <div class="mySlides1">
       <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
 
     <div class="caption-container">
       <p id="caption1"></p>
     </div>
 
 
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- end ligtbox2 -->
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <!-- this ligtbox3 -->
 <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox3</h2>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
   <div class="modal-content">
 
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
 
     <div class="caption-container">
       <p id="caption2"></p>
     </div>
 
 
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<!-- end lightbox3 -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the code due to incorrect usage of couple of Javascript and HTML concepts such as:

- The ids for element should be unique ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)). In the code `myModal` is used as the id multiple times. Have fixed the same to create multiple unique ids such as myModal1, myModal2, myModal3.
- One needs to pass the context properly while calling the function. Both the `openModal` and `closeModal` function *are not taking any arguments*. The value of id is hardcoded to `myModal` and hence it always refers to the first element with id as myModal and so, LightBox1 becomes visible. To fix that, have explicitly passed the ids while calling the function and saved it in a global variable for later usage (*Note: Usage of global variable is bad. Have fixed the code in little haste so used global variable* [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)).
- `getElementsByClassName` takes only one argument, in the code it is taking two arguments at multiple places. Have fixed the same ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)).

Have fixed the code for you and made it working for the mentioned case in the question. But there are some places where code it still wrong, that can be fixed by looking at the fixed code.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

```js
let modalId = "";

function openModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  modalId = id;
}

function closeModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  if (!document.getElementById(modalId)) return;
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementById(modalId).getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  //   for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  //             slides[i].style.display = "none";
  //         }
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo", "demo1");
  //   for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  //    dots[i].style.display = "block";            
  //         }
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption", "caption1");
  //   for (var i = 0; i < captionText.length; i++) {
  //    captionText[i].style.display = "block";            
  //         }
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row>.column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides.mySlides1.mySlides2 {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox1</h2>
<!-- this for lightbox 1 -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal1');currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal1')">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end lightbox1 -->
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- this for lighbox2 -->
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox2</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2');currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2');currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2');currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal2');currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal2')">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption1"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end ligtbox2 -->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- this ligtbox3 -->
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox3</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal3');currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal3');currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal3');currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal('myModal3');currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal('myModal3')">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption2"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end lightbox3 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i mean want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides1.mySlides2.mySlides3 {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}


.demo1.demo2.demo3 {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo1.demo2.demo3:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox1</h2>
<!-- this for lightbox 1 -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal1();currentSlide1(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal1();currentSlide1(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal1();currentSlide1(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal1();currentSlide1(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal1()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img  src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img id="ok2" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img  src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img  src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides1(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides1(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption1"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img id="ok1" class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/j7xx4uDVoCo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide1(1)" alt="kui1">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img id="ok2" class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZS67i1HLllo/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide1(2)" alt="Snow1">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img id="ok3" class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/YiX1jsdbWhY/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide1(3)" alt="Mountains1">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img id="ok4" class="demo1 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/jafl5owXXVc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide1(4)" alt="Northern1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end lightbox1 -->
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- this for lighbox2 -->
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox2</h2>
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal2();currentSlide2(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal2();currentSlide2(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal2();currentSlide2(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal2();currentSlide2(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal2()">&times;</span>
   <div class="modal-content">
 
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <div class="mySlides2">
       <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides2(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides2(1)">&#10095;</a>
 
     <div class="caption-container">
       <p id="caption2"></p>
     </div>
 
 
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/0qvBNep1Y04/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(1)" alt="Nature2">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/BfrQnKBulYQ/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(2)" alt="Snow2">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/9wTPJmiXk2U/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(3)" alt="Mountai2">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo2 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/O2MdroNurVw/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(4)" alt="Northern2">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- end ligtbox2 -->
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <!-- this ligtbox3 -->
 <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox3</h2>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal3();currentSlide3(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal3();currentSlide3(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal3();currentSlide3(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal3();currentSlide3(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal3()">&times;</span>
   <div class="modal-content">
 
     <div class="mySlides3">
       <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides3">
       <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
 
     <div class="mySlides3">
       <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <div class="mySlides3">
       <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides3(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides3(1)">&#10095;</a>
 
     <div class="caption-container">
       <p id="caption3"></p>
     </div>
 
 
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo3 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/gnyA8vd3Otc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide3(1)" alt="Nature3">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo3 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/g5jpH62pwes/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide3(2)" alt="Snow3">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo3 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/JpF58ANavoc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide3(3)" alt="Mountains3">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo3 cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/mZRCMPbJSPc/1600x900" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide3(4)" alt="Northern3">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<!-- end lightbox3 -->
<!-- javascipt,html,and css from w3school -->
<script>

    //  for lighbox1
    function openModal1() {
      document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function closeModal1() {
      document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "none";
    }
// -------------------------
    var slideIndex1 = 1;
    showSlides1(slideIndex1);
    
    function plusSlides1(n) {
      showSlides1(slideIndex1 += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide1(n) {
      showSlides1(slideIndex1 = n);
    }
 // lighbox1
 function showSlides1(n) {
      var i;
      var slides1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
      var dots1 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo1");
      var captionText1 = document.getElementById("caption1");
      var x1 = document.getElementById("ok1").alt;
      var x2 = document.getElementById("ok2").alt;
      var x3 = document.getElementById("ok3").alt;
      var x4 = document.getElementById("ok4").alt;
// lighbox 1
      if (n > slides1.length) {slideIndex1 = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex1 = slides1.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides1.length; i++) {
          slides1[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots1.length; i++) {
          dots1[i].className = dots1[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides1[slideIndex1-1].style.display = "block";
      dots1[slideIndex1-1].className += " active";
      captionText1.innerHTML = dots1[slideIndex1-1].alt;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------
   //  =======================================
    // ---------------------------------------
    // ---------------------------------------
   //  =======================================
    // for lighbox2
    function openModal2() {
      document.getElementById("myModal2").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function closeModal2() {
      document.getElementById("myModal2").style.display = "none";
    }
   //  --------------------
    var slideIndex2 = 1;
    showSlides2(slideIndex2);
    
    function plusSlides2(u) {
      showSlides2(slideIndex2 += u);
    }
    
    function currentSlide2(u) {
      showSlides2(slideIndex2 = u);
    }
     // lighbox2
     function showSlides2(u){
      var j;
      var slides2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
      var dots2 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo2");
      var captionText2 = document.getElementById("caption2");

      // lighbox 2
      if (u > slides2.length) {slideIndex2 = 1}
      if (u < 1) {slideIndex2 = slides2.length}
      for (j = 0; j < slides2.length; j++) {
          slides2[j].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (j = 0; j < dots2.length; j++) {
          dots2[j].className = dots2[j].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides2[slideIndex2-1].style.display = "block";
      dots2[slideIndex2-1].className += " active";
      captionText2.innerHTML = dots2[slideIndex2-1].alt;
    }
    // ---------------------------------------
    // ---------------------------------------
   //  =======================================
    // for lighbox3
    function openModal3() {
      document.getElementById("myModal3").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function closeModal3() {
      document.getElementById("myModal3").style.display = "none";
    }
   //  --------------------
    var slideIndex3 = 1;
    showSlides3(slideIndex3);
    
    function plusSlides3(p) {
      showSlides3(slideIndex3 += p);
    }
    
    function currentSlide3(p) {
      showSlides3(slideIndex3 = p);
    }
     // lighbox3
     function showSlides3(p){
      var k;
      var slides3 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides3");
      var dots3 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo3");
      var captionText3 = document.getElementById("caption3");

      // lighbox 3
      if (p > slides3.length) {slideIndex3 = 1}
      if (p < 1) {slideIndex3 = slides3.length}
      for (k = 0; k < slides3.length; k++) {
          slides3[k].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (k = 0; k < dots3.length; k++) {
          dots3[k].className = dots3[k].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides3[slideIndex3-1].style.display = "block";
      dots3[slideIndex3-1].className += " active";
      captionText3.innerHTML = dots3[slideIndex3-1].alt;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm, could have accept Sunil's answer here since he did quite an effort and spent some time with your issue. Accepting your own answer doesn't reward him anyhow, you neither (you will not get your reputation back).

Comment: ive accept sunnils answer,instead ive thanked him,but somehow my comment sudenly dissapeared. i dont know why these happen...

Comment: This happens because a "thank you" is useless on StackOverflow, hence it's deleted to avoid useless noise (more details in the tour/guide). If you want to thank somebody, drop a like and accept the answer if it solved your issue, no need for more.

Comment: Your code is just purely wrong. Programming is not about copy/pasting code. Imagine you needed 100 slideshows... You only need one reusable function (component, class). Not hundreds. Imagine going to fix a bug on all of them...  or just adding a slide on one of them. Also it's a waste of memory resources. Hard to debug, error prone and hard to maintain.

Comment: **This is not an answer**, if you wanted to **[edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72697582/edit)** (to insert a *preview* of the needed behavior) you could have done so.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan looks like a solution to me. I don't see the need to downvote nor bash here. It's OP's safe space and even if he accepted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72748796/8816585), he had figured out an answer himself (different from the accepted one). Comments regarding that were deleted but I saw those.

Comment: @kissu not bashing. It's instructing OP to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72697582/edit) instead of providing additional context to the question in the Answer section. Also, the answer (if it *is* one) is not in the expected Q&A format for this site. Read: [Help Center: How do I provide a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan asking and answering his own question is [totally fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It's not providing more context but really answering OP's question, as you can see the issue is solved. A huge wall of code is totally okay if it works. At least, it suits OP's needs. I do agree that this could benefit from some formatting polishing but overall, it's fine from SO's standing point.