# C#, DataTable to ArrayList?

Tags: c#, datatable, arraylist

I have a datatable with few rows each row has few columns.
I want to create an arraylist that countain all row as a string
so each array item look like this `{1;qwqww;qweqweqwe;qweqweqw;qwe}`
The items in the string will be separated with `;`
and it is a .NET 2 solution

Thanks

Comment: all columns contain strings ?

Comment: yes (one is boolean) but it will be used as "true" "false"

Comment: [Don't do it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434414/what-is-the-most-evil-code-you-have-ever-seen-in-a-production-enterprise-environm/434562#434562)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution that actually works.

```
ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
    rows.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));
```

However, I feel I should point out that it is unwise to use the obsolete `ArrayList`. Use `List<string>` instead, since the rows are strings:

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>();
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString) does not work for me!

I'm using .NET v2 is there any thing to do with it ?

Comment: @Data-Base: Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `ArrayList` I would recommend you using a strongly typed collection because an `ArrayList` wouldn't bring much value compared to a non-strongly typed `DataTable`. So you could start by defining a model that will represent each row:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

then loop over your `DataTable` and fill the collection:

```
List<MyModel> models = new List<MyModel>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel 
    {
        Id = (int)row[0],
        Prop1 = (string)row[1],
        Prop2 = (string)row[2]
    };
    models.Add(model);
}
```

Or you could use LINQ if you prefer:

```
List<MyModel> models = dt.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new MyModel { 
        Id = (int)row[0],
        Prop1 = (string)row[1],
        Prop2 = (string)row[2]
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice, but what if the rows in the datatable varied and wasn't always 3?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in ((DataTable)dataGrid.DataSource).Rows)
{
    rows.Add(String.Join(";", (string[])dataRow.ItemArray));
}
```

Comment: you mean ";" andnot "," in rows.Add(String.Join(",", (string[])dataRow.ItemArray)); ?

Comment: I suspect that the cast to `string[]` will generally fail.

Comment: @Data-Base - yes, fixed it, thanks!

@Timwi - I asked what the array items type would be, it looks like he only expects string

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory:
This is a code fragment that I use to write a CSV for a datatable:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        WriteItem(stream, row[i], quoteall);
        if (i < table.Columns.Count - 1)
            stream.Write(',');
        else
            stream.Write('\n');
    }
}
```

Use StringBuffer instead of WriteItem ... stream etc...

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, I'll find out how to put code in properly

Answer (score -2):

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList(dt.Rows.Count);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    aList.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: how the items will be separated in the string? is it by "," or ";"?

Comment: Doesn't work, he wants each array item as a single string, not a datarow

Comment: oh.. I missed that fact in his question!