# how to get dataTable from arraylist in which dataTable is stored?

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have an `ArrayList` , it has a `string` at 0th position and `DataTable` at 1st position 
is it possible to get `DataTable` back?

```
ArrayList dataModel = new ArrayList();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A");
dt.Columns.Add("B");
dt.Columns.Add("C");
dt.Rows.Add("1","Rahul","Vapi");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "Yash", "Vapi");
dt.Rows.Add("3", "Dinesh", "vapi");

dataModel.Add("this is working for me");
dataModel.Add(dt);
```

I am getting this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: That's so wrong...how about using a `List<Dictionary<string,DataTable>>`

Comment: @Pikoh: sure, you should not need to use an `ArrayList` anymore. But your example doesn't help. OP has only two items, a string and a `DataTable`. So if you want to replace this with a generic collection you need to use a `List<Object>` in which case you also need to cast the items.

Comment: @pikoh: because that's how OP uses the arraylist. He doesn't need a way to store multiple string-DataTable combinations which you could handle with a `List<Dictionary<string,DataTable>>`. There is only one string and one DataTable. Of course he should use two separate variables(local variables, properties or fields) instead or a class that encapsulates both.

Comment: Please try this Datatable to Arraylist http://stackoverflow.com/a/3573771/1849024

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, now i see. Anyway, i would use a `Dictionary<string,DataTable>` and that way you won't need to cast the datatable back. Or,as you say,a class.

Comment: @pikoh: If you want to support multiple it would be much better to provide a custom class with two properties and then use a `List<MyCustomClass>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter agreed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (are you missing a cast?)

Yes.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable) dataModel[1];
```